# Safe and reliable way to enable NSAppTransportSecurity for Release configuration and disable it for Debug/Staging configurations?

Tags: ios, charles-proxy, app-transport-security

The question says it all.

I am aware of `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` that can be taken together `NSExceptionDomains` but I am bit confused by this blacklisting approach: I don't want to disable ATS for everything except specific production hosts listed by `NSExceptionDomains` because they are subject to change and so I would need to manage their list together with general app configuration where we have 3+ different host types for production. [Of course in a perfect world Apple would suggest us to list the hosts for which we want disable App Transport Security and have it enabled for all other hosts - Not! vice versa]

I also tried to inherit my user-defined setting `$(MY_USER_SETTING)` (which can support 3 different values corresponding to Debug/Staging/Release) but it does not play well with non-string types of `NSAppTransportSecurity` which is dictionary and `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` boolean – those values just don't inherit my user-defined setting.

Background: I want to be able to see the HTTP trafic of our Debug/Staging configurations using Charles Proxy and as of iOS 9 it requires that ATS to be disabled and I want to make sure that this will not affect our Release configuration in any way!

Comment: You can add a build phase to run a script that edits the plist in your debug builds. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912743/ios-changing-info-plist-during-build-phase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In contrast to what one may think (one example: [WORKING WITH APPLE’S APP TRANSPORT SECURITY](http://www.neglectedpotential.com/2015/06/working-with-apples-application-transport-security/)) `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` DOES NOT work as flag which toggles between blacklisting/whitelisting modes at least it does not play well with Charles:

**Blacklisting approach (DOES NOT WORK FOR ME IN IOS 9.0 - Charles does not recognize traffic from/to staging host):**

> Example B: ATS for all, with some exceptions
>
> If you expect all of your domains to work with ATS, except a few that you know will not work, you can specify exceptions for where ATS should not be use, while leaving all other traffic opted in. For this scenario, you’ll want to use an NSExceptionDomains to specify the domains for which you wish to override ATS’s default settings.

**Whitelisting approach (WORKS, but not really a nice way of doing this):** If `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` is set to `YES` then Application Transport Security feature is **disabled** for all the domains except those that listed under `NSExceptionDomains`.

> Example C: ATS disabled, with some exceptions
>
> Conversely, you may only want ATS to work on domains you specifically know can support it. For example, if you developer a Twitter client, there will be countless URLs you may want to load that may not be able to support ATS, though you would want things like login calls, and other requests to Twitter to use ATS. In this case you can disable ATS as your default, then specify URL which you do wish to use ATS.

---

Another approach described here: [This One Weird Trick Makes Developing iOS Apps Against a Local Server Way Easier](http://www.jackflintermann.com/developing-ios-apps-against-a-local-server) suggests adding "Run Script Build Phase" which uses PlistBuddy to patch application's plist file on a fly. Here's their example for making app to not use ATS when developer works against a server on his local machine (of course could be staging host as well):

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :NSAppTransportSecurity:NSExceptionDomains:$LOCAL_NETWORK_NAME:NSIncludesSubdomains bool true" $INFO_PLIST
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :NSAppTransportSecurity:NSExceptionDomains:$LOCAL_NETWORK_NAME:NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads bool true" $INFO_PLIST
```

---

IMO, patching Plist is a better way to conditionally disable ATS for staging hosts than using Whitelisting approach described above so we'll stick with PlistBuddy.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have your answer right there.
ATS is enabled by default for all hosts.
If you disable it only for staging hosts, then your production endpoints are not affected by this.
That is, simply add your staging domain to the exception domains and that's that.
Or did I misunderstand the specifics of your question?

Comment: What if you don't want your staging domain to be visible into the application bundle your publish to the store ?